# Unable to add firebase support for Ionic4 and Angular fire

Tags: angular, firebase, cordova, ionic4

I have started project using Ionic4 and AngularFire2 (Angular and Firebase). I am having all the latest dependencies.

Everything works fine if I am running things in web. But as soon as I try same thing in mobile (using capacitor and cordova) it is not working.

I tried to follow this [article](https://javebratt.com/ionic-social-login-firebase/) , now it is running, not working and no error is coming. Again I have tried with both options.

Here are two question
1. Should I go native route (like ionic/native plugins) and try to use firebase auth
2. Is there any latest documentation or working example of the same? I tried to find out but couldn't found one.

Article is using something called universal-links-plugin and that project is archived so can't ask question there.

It would be great if help someone can point me into direction, for using Angular + Firebase + Ionic4 + mobile (capacitor is possible else cordova).

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: use https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks instead universal-links-plugin

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari thanks for link I will give it a try. BTW is there any step by step guide to set up all things?

Comment: your question is not clear. what you facing.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari I can't make angular-fire run with cordova or capacitor. It is working great if I am running things in web.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari BTW I tried that plugin. It didn't help. Still not working. And no error in terminal as such.

Comment: put code how you implemented so far

Comment: angularfire2 is library for firebase. angularfire2 is fine with web. i will suggest use ionic native for firebase(notification, analytics or anything)

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari I was following docs for angular fire only. I check it out ionic native part of it. And ionic native plugin is not having all the functionality of social login.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help you without more information, can you share some code or repository? So we can see what you tried and maybe point you in the right direction. At least try to share if there are mobile errors while building/running the app ( you can use safari for iphone or chrome for android to debug).

1. From what you've posted so far, my best guess is you didn't install `npm i firebase`, but hard to say without more information
2. Good documentation on using ionic3/4 with angularFire2 is available on: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/v3.md

Hope this helps you along, if it doesn't, please try to provide more information.

Comment: There was issue of not getting all details out. But if I remember correctly, I did solved by integrating native plugin for authentication. Thanks for reply @Ben